# HighChart JavaSCript two spline updating in the same graphic

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I have one spline updating each minute. What I need to do is to put another spline with different color into the same graphic.

So I just copied the same JavaScript code again, it works fine with a different color but it overwrites the first one. Of course it's to be expected but I don't know what to change to visualize two spline at the same time.

I'm new to JavaScript, so thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use addSeries() function to add new series with separate color: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()